# Cant seem to cast the Chronometer to an int

Tags: java, android-studio, chronometer

I am trying to convert the chronometer to seconds but cant seem to cast it as an int.
As I need to put the seconds on a new activity.

**Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.widget.Chronometer' to 'int'**

```
 private Chronometer chronometer;
    private  boolean ChronometerRunnin;
    private  long pauseOffset;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // ButterKnife.bind(this);
        chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometerT);
        chronometer.setFormat("Timer: %s");
        buttonStats = findViewById(R.id.btRun);
        buttonStats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openStatsPage();

            }
        });
    }

    public void openStatsPage(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StatsPage.class);

        
         int elapsedMillis = (int) chronometer /1000;

        float timerdata = Integer.valueOf(chronometer.getText().toString());

        intent.putExtra("timedata",timerdata);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: If the string from the chronometer is formatted as "Timer: 00:03" then it is a NumberFormatException, you can't cast this string to an integer.

Comment: Also you you can't declare float timerdata = Integer.valueOf(..) because timerdata is expecting a float, but Integer.valueOf returns an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast a Chronometer type to int, you need to call the `getBase()` method.

Try to change your openStatsPage method like this

```
int elapsedTimeInSec = (int) ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, StatsPage.class);
intent.putExtra("timedata", elapsedTimeInSec);

startActivity(intent);
```